# What are the physiological effects of retinal exposure to 380–400nm light?

Tags: human-biology, medicine, human-eye, light

There are two categories of sunglasses: UV380 sunglasses block all light with wavelength 380nm or lower, while UV400 sunglasses block all light with wavelength 400nm or lower.

This made me wonder, what are the physiological effects of retinal exposure to the 380–400nm band of light, which is not covered by UV380 sunglasses?

Also, assuming that the 380–400nm UV light does cause eye damage, does any potential pupil dilation caused by the dark tint of such glasses have an effect on the amount of damage caused?

Comment: I suggest editing your question to remove all references to possible health effects and just focus on the scientific question of the physiological effects of retinal exposure to 380-400nm light. Make it a science question, not a personal health one.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to do just that.

Comment: Looks much better.

Comment: dunno but long term exposure would increase the risk of cateracts later on, just getting a milky zone on the iris. I think that's one of the main things that sunglasses protect from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after thorough research:

### Definitions

First, I noticed that there is no consensus on where the UV spectrum ends and the blue portion of the visible light spectrum begins.

According to the WHO, as well as to most other sources, the UV spectrum covers the wavelength range 100–400nm [(1)](https://www.who.int/uv/uv_and_health/en/). However, a few other sources, notably the [SCENIHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Committee_on_Emerging_and_Newly_Identified_Health_Risks), define visible light as starting at 380nm [(2)](https://ec.europa.eu/health/ph_risk/committees/04_scenihr/docs/scenihr_o_019.pdf), hence UV light would be 100–380nm.

Another source, the [ICNIRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Commission_on_Non-Ionizing_Radiation_Protection), directly mentions that the boundary is not clear-cut, “the band 315 to 380–400 nm is designated as UVA” [(3)](https://www.icnirp.org/cms/upload/publications/ICNIRPUV2004.pdf) . At least one source refers to the 385–405nm band as the “UV/Visible Radiation Boundary Region” [(4)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-30738-6).

### Tinted Lenses

To address the part about the dark tint of lenses causing pupil dilation, it is first worth noting that not all lenses that filter out UV light have a dark tint.
In fact, clear lenses can actually offer up to UV400 protection [(5)](https://www.zeiss.com/vision-care/int/spectacle-lenses-from-zeiss/full-uv-protection-in-all-clear-lenses.html). There is even some research specifically on UV protection by clear lenses [(6)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5905936/).

### Back reflection of UV light

UV380 and UV400 are not the only eyeglass specifications relevant to UV protection. There is also eye-sun protection factor (E-SPF®), which was introduced in order to also account for back reflection of UV light from eyeglass lenses to the eyes [(7)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24379652/). Therefore, this back reflection should also be taken into account when examining the effects of 380–400nm light exposure on the eye.

### The 380–400nm Band

Now let’s get to answering the question.

According to the Texas Technical University Health Sciences Center, 40% of the radiation harmful to our eyes falls within 380–400nm, which they call the “UV protection gap” [(8)](https://www.ttuhsc.edu/medicine/ophthalmology/documents/The_Invisible_Truth_about_UV_Protection.pdf). Another source states that, while 100–380nm light is “very harmful”, 400–460nm blue light can still cause retinal damage and macular degeneration [(9)](https://www.eyetrusteyecare.ca/research-on-blue-light-and-the-affects-to-your-eyes/). The American Optometric Association also states that blue light, which they define as the range 380–500nm, may cause eye damage [(10)](https://www.aoa.org/Documents/CRG/Blue%20Light%20and%20Eye%20Damage.pdf).

An article by ZEISS Vision Care explains that the UV380 standard was a “pragmatic choice” by the ophthalmic industry, and does not reflect “biomedical realities” [(11)](https://www.zeiss.com/vision-care/int/about-us/newsroom/news-overview/2019/zeiss-uvprotect-protection-against-harmful-uv-radiation.html). The article refers to the 380–400nm spectrum as the “most intense portion of solar UVR on Earth”. I assume the author is referring to the physical definition of intensity of radiant energy, which is the power transferred per unit area, however I am not 100% sure that this is the intended meaning of “most intense”.

I also found an article claiming that the WHO recommends UV protection up to 400nm [(12)](https://www.uvex-safety.co.uk/en/how-uv-rays-can-damage-eyes/), which again implies that 380–400nm does cause significant retinal damage. However, I couldn’t find the actual WHO publication stating the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome hb20007,

I would like to introduce the types of Ultraviolet light to you first.

> - Ultraviolet A - UVA - 400–315 nanometers
> - Ultraviolet B - UVB - 315–280 nanometers
> - Ultraviolet C - UVC - 280–100 nanometers

UV380 sunglasses block all light with a wavelength < 380nm. Blocking **most UVA**, UVB & UVC.

UV400 sunglasses block all light with a wavelength < 400nm. Blocking **all UVA**, UVB & UVC.

The first article you attached is poorly written. It states that quality control is at fault by some sunglasses manufacturers. Meaning some sunglasses aren't made right because they do not meet appropriate manufacturing standards. Therefore they are damaging to eyes. Which is true.

The second article is also true.

UV380 sunglasses are fine for UV eye protection, if you would like greater protection from ultraviolet light (all of UVA), then buy UV400 sunglasses.

I talk more about ultraviolet (UV) light and it's cancerous consequences [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24143/does-the-damage-from-sun-exposure-outweigh-the-benefit-of-getting-vitamin-d/24171#24171).

[Wikipedia has well-written free scientific information that I would highly recommend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet).

Comment: You did not address the apparent trade-off where wearing UV380 sunglasses dilates pupils but does not fully block UV light. I would like to have more information regarding this point. All I could find was [this](https://www.allaboutvision.com/askdoc/sunglasses.htm), which mentions pupil dilation and goes on to say that 100% UV protection is important.

Comment: In the original first article you reference, it is the 'Dark lenses' they are talking about that cause dilates pupils. Not the UV380 sunglasses, hope that is helpful.

Comment: True, but UV380 sunglasses will also cause dilation while not offering full UV protection. I'm interested to see if there is any research on the effects of the 380nm-400nm UV band on the eyes.

Comment: There is no evidence that UV380 sunglasses causes pupil dilation. As for your other question, nothing came up when I searched it on google scholar. It may not be ethical for animal models, and it is definitely not ethical for humans to be exposed to UV light of an exact band. Unfortunately I don't believe this is an area this we as humans know much about.

Comment: UV380 sunglasses, as well as any other form of sunglasses, would cause pupil dilation because of their dark tint.

Comment: Correct, the dark tint is what causes the pupil dilation. The dark tint the sunglasses they are referring to in that article is from faulty manufacturing - not from their ability to protect UV light < UV380.